# In mysql dynamic stored proc, is @var required to build a prepared statement?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I have a similar stored proc (but longer).  It is called from PHP (GET request on Apache)

```
delimiter // 
CREATE PROCEDURE dynamic(IN tbl CHAR(64), IN col CHAR(64))
BEGIN
    SET @full_statement = CONCAT('SELECT ',col,' FROM ',tbl );
    PREPARE stmt FROM @full_statement;
    EXECUTE stmt;
END
//
delimiter ;
```

From what I read, @s is a mysql session variable living as long as my session is alive.
The @s presence annoys me since I fear that 2 concurrent request on that stored
proc might play with this "global variable".  So I tried to remove the '@' like this

```
delimiter // 
CREATE PROCEDURE dynamic(IN tbl CHAR(64), IN col CHAR(64))
BEGIN
    DECLARE full_statement VARCHAR(300);
    SET full_statement = CONCAT('SELECT ',col,' FROM ',tbl );
    PREPARE stmt FROM full_statement;
    EXECUTE stmt;
END
//
delimiter ;
```

to build the prepared statement without success.

I seem to have constantly

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'full_statement;    EXECUTE stmt;

- Does my fear of 2 calls within my php session is really a problem ? 
  (If not, what about having 200 stored procedures using that same
  global variable) ?
- Can I really achieve my goal and remove the '@' and let the prepared
  statement being handle by a simple stored proc variable or is it a constraint of prepared statement ?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, the @var is required.**

MySQL's PREPARE statement only accepts "user variables" (those prefixed with `@`), not local variables declared in a stored routine.

This has long been recognized as a WTF in MySQL:

- [Bug #17409 PREPARE doesn't support queries in local variables](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=17409)

> Does my fear of 2 calls within my php session is really a problem ?

No.  It's not a global variable, it's a session variable.
Two concurrent sessions have their own value for @var.

Comment: Excellent, I realize that I over-considered the database connect session, thinking of the "session variable" as per user's php cookie session.  Am I right ? The 2 concurrent request mentionned are actually 2 ajax request from a browser to the same php session.  Based on your answer, I conclude that 2 php requests will have their own mysql session, therefore, no possible conflict is possible ?

Comment: I meant over-considered => under-considered

Comment: Correct -- PHP is "shared nothing" so each request gets its own MySQL connection (aka MySQL session).